# Why does /includegraphics not find image if run in process

Tags: luatex, includegraphics

I have a `tex` file which `\includegraphics` an image in the same directory. If the file is run with `texstudio` the image is included.

If the same file is run in a process started from a program, the file is not found. It is found if the address is a full path, but not found with a relative path (relative to the `tex` file, like `\includegraphics{DSC08138.JPG}`.  What can cause this?

`lualatex` is called with the arguments `-interaction=nonstopmode --output-directory=dir1 filename.tex` where  `dir1` is the directory in which the `filename.tex` and the image is stored.

The relevant part of the code is:

```
putIOwords ["writePDF2text 1 infn", showT infn]
let dir1 = getParentDir fnres :: FilePath
let out1 = "--output-directory=" <> (dir1)
putIOwords ["writePDF2text 2 out1", showT out1]
callIO $ Sys.callProcess
    "lualatex"
    [out1, "-interaction=nonstopmode", toFilePath infn]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program should be started from the directory where the filename.tex resides, or should perform `cd` (change directory) to that directory (variable dir1) before running lualatex (luatex has no "--input-directory" switch).

Sorry I don't recognize the code sample (Basic-ish?), so I can't show the exact fix at this time.

If it is "DOS" style batch scripting, then the `cd` command is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I was under the assumption that the tex file is interpreted in the directory it is in, but - as you point out - it uses the current working directory. I have changed the (Haskell) code and it does indeed solve the problem.